# JavaScript Increment operator weird expression

Tags: javascript, increment

Why the output of the bellow expression is 2,1?

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2

a = (b+=a -=b)-a

console.log(`${a,b}`)
```

Comment: It is not, the output is 1

Comment: Did you mean ```console.log(`${a},${b}`)```?

Comment: What do you expect it to be? Note that `+=` and `-=` have the same precedence but right-to-left associativity.

Comment: Because of that, you can re-write as `a = (b += (a -= b)) - a`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that is what I mean thanks...  console.log(`${a},${b}`)

Comment: Well explained. got it! thanks @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
a = (b+=a-=b)-a (*)

a-=b means a = a-b = 1-2 = -1
a = -1
Substitute into (*) => a = (b+=(-1))-a
b+=(-1) means b=b + (-1) = b - 1 = 1

Substitute into (*) => a = (1)-a = 1-(-1) = 2
a=2 b=1
```